# Report viewer taking a long time to load reports

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, reportviewer, report-designer

I have an form that prints all items, This is what the users sees when the form is first loaded:

[image]
This report prints multiple pages with only 9 columns changing each time. There are a total of 4652 pages total and it takes 5 minutes to load all those pages onto the report viewer. Each item has two pages there are a total of 2326 items.

When the user click print preview

**page 1 of report**

[image]

**page 2 of report **

[image]
 The second time i ran the same report it loaded the report from cache in a time of 1 and 1/2 minute that is a significant difference

My question is what can i do to enhance the performance of the report. The database and application are on the same machine and the performance is terrible, the user wants to install the application at the 4 plants with sql server and the performance is going to be a even bigger problem due to the fact that multiple people will be accessing the application, we will have network bottlenecks. From Sql Server point of view i added indexes, updated the statistics, try to see if there is a way i can make the query fetch the results faster but from a report viewer and report designer point of view i am clueless any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add non-clustered indexes to the columns your are using in your Where clause.

Comment: i added non-clustered indexes, the performance is only faster on the SQL Server Side but my report viewer is still taking a long time to load all the report pages with the data.

Answer (score 0):

If real time data is not a must (say, half an hour or an hour delay is acceptable), you could try to use Report Snapshots.

In simple terms, it generates report beforehand, and keeps it for a certain amount of time, thus making loading should almost always be instant. The catch, like I have mentioned above, is that the report does not always shows the latest data.

http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/report-snapshots-in-ssrs/